# java: exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Chain_of_Responsibility

Tags: java, linux, exception

My question is the following:
   I have a java code, written in one .java file - Chain_of_Responsibility, the code is in the end of my question.
   I compiled it on Linux with

```
javac Chain_of_Responsibility.java
```

And get all my .class files in same directory. Then I try to run my program with

```
java Chain_of_Responsibility
```

And get " exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Chain_of_Responsibility". I've try to make my main function static, write all my classes in different .java files, but without success. So I have no idea what to do. Can you help me?

```
package COR;

public class Chain_of_Responsibility
{
public void main(String[] args)
{
    //Create the Chain of Responsibility

    Handler chain = build_chain();

    //Trying to handle the request (valid are cheese, meet or banana)

    chain.handle_request(args[1]);
}

private Handler build_chain()
{
    //Creating the chain

    Handler monkey = new Monkey();
    Handler wolve = new Wolve();
    Handler mouse = new Mouse();

    //First nide is Monkey, then Wolve and then Mouse

    monkey.set_next_handler(wolve);
    wolve.set_next_handler(mouse);

    //Returning the first node in the chain

    return monkey;
}
}

abstract class Handler
{
Handler next_handler;

public void set_next_handler(Handler next_handler)  
{
    //Setting next handler in the chain

    this.next_handler = next_handler;
}

public abstract void handle_request(String request);
}

class Mouse extends Handler
{
public void handle_request(String request)
{
    //Trying to handle the request

    if (request == "cheese")
    {
        //Succesful try

        System.out.println("Mouse handles cheese!");
    }
    else
    {
        //Cannot handle request

        System.out.println("Mouse in unable to handle cheese" +  request + "!");

        if (next_handler != null)
        {
            //Sending request to the next handler

            next_handler.handle_request(request);
        }
        else
        {
            //If there is no handlers left, alert about crash

            System.out.println("Chain ends without success!");
        }
    }
}
}

class Wolve extends Handler
{
public void handle_request(String request)
{
    //Trying to handle the request

    if (request == "meet")
    {
        //Succesful try

        System.out.println("Wolve handles meet!");
    }
    else
    {
        //Cannot handle request

        System.out.println("Wolve in unable to handle cheese" +  request + "!");

        if (next_handler != null)
        {
            //Sending request to the next handler

            next_handler.handle_request(request);
        }
        else
        {
            //If there is no handlers left, alert about crash

            System.out.println("Chain ends without success!");
        }
    }
}
}

class Monkey extends Handler
{
public void handle_request(String request)
{
    //Trying to handle the request

    if (request == "banana")
    {
        //Succesful try

        System.out.println("Monkey handles banana!");
    }
    else
    {
        //Cannot handle request

        System.out.println("Monkey in unable to handle" +  request + "!");

        if (next_handler != null)
        {
            //Sending request to the next handler

            next_handler.handle_request(request);
        }
        else
        {
            //If there is no handlers left, alert about crash

            System.out.println("Chain ends without success!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: will you accept an answer in a near future ?

Answer (score 6):

Try `java COR.Chain_Of_Responsibility` and make your `main` method `static`

**EDIT**

you have to launch `java...` at the root of your project, e.g. `/src` if your Chain_of_responsibiliy.java is in `/src/COR`

Comment: @dounyy from which language is this custom? PHP?

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't know, but this java speaker has a terrible accent

Comment: I make my main method static, run java COR.Chain_of_Responsibility, and get "Error: Could not find or load main class COR.Chain_of_Responsibility".

Comment: What about my accent in Java, I learn it for myself and traditions I keep in my C++ programs are still strong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that your directory structure matches your package structure. This means that, since your class is in a package named `COR`, the source file should be in a directory named `COR`.

So, assuming that your project is in `C:\MyProject`, you should have a directory named `C:\MyProject\COR` that contains the source file `Chain_of_Responsibility.java`.

Then compile and run it from the directory `C:\MyProject`:

```
C:\MyProject> javac COR\Chain_of_Responsibility.java
C:\MyProject> java COR.Chain_of_Responsibility
```

Note: The `javac` command expects the path to the source file; the `java` command expects a fully-qualified class name (not the path to the class file).

If the above doesn't work, then you most likely have the `CLASSPATH` environment variable set. You can override that by explicitly specifying the classpath with the `-cp` option:

```
C:\MyProject> java -cp . COR.Chain_of_Responsibility
```

(Also, your `main` method must be `static`, as others have already noted).