# Unable to run Java program

Tags: java

I'm having trouble running my very first piece of java.  I was able to compile it and produce a .class file, but then I was unable to run it for some reason.  It might have something to do with the directory path.  The file name is "Simple" and I have this saved in a folder called "newfolder".

I was able to compile Simple.class by typing in "javac newfolder/Simple.java", but when I typed in "java newfolder/Simple", this message appeared:

```
java: exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: newfolder/Simple (wrong name: Simple)
```

Here is the original code that I typed in:

```
// This is a simple Java program.

public class Simple
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     System.out.println("Hello World");
   }
}
```

I think that [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253100/java-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-chain-of-respon) is up my alley, but I've somehow been unable to get it to work for me, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into your packaging of your class and the way you call the class to execute. The correct format of running java program is "java -cp [classpath] [package path]/JavaClassName"

Answer (score 3):

Try running the Java file from inside the newfolder/

```
cd newfolder/
java Simple
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed to get things running :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want to use an IDE which sets up these things for you but you need

```
package newfolder;
```

at the start.